# how to increment a number i-e (yyyy-number) in oracle

Tags: oracle

I want to insert in a primary key a record i-e (yyyy-number) for example (2017-1) which is automatically increment by "1" in oracle. please help me.
thanks in advance.....

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [ask] and [mcve] before posting  question.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it in "before insert trigger". Or split value on two columns and concat them when show.